# Help locating GFCI reset for exterior outlets

Tags: gfci

I have lost power to my exterior outlets.  I have gone through the house resetting GFCI outlets in the kitchen, garage and bathrooms with no luck.  I also looked and found no GFCI outlets outside.  I reset all GFCI breakers on panel with no success.  Inspection of the crawl space and found no outlets.

The house was built in 2014 so there should be a reset somewhere.  Any suggestions on what to try next?

Comment: Have you _tested_ the GFCIs to ensure that they're actually functional? I believe that just hitting the `Reset` button won't help much if the outlet itself isn't actually working. I'm not 100% certain, but I believe that if the GFCI circuitry has failed, it will cause power to the outlet itself and downstream LOAD side outlets to be off as a protective measure.

Comment: Have you also inspected the standard breakers? Maybe it was an overcurrent and not a ground fault. Of course it could also be a bad connection somewhere.

Comment: What makes you believe it's a GFCI trip and not any other kind of wiring issue? (e.g. "it happened right after I used my GFCI tester" is a great answer).  Do you know which circuit breaker the outside outlets are on? Is anything else on it?

Comment: Thanks for the input and suggestions.  I. purchased a circuit tracer and found the GFCI breaker on the panel.  This has 2 white wires and a single black wire coming into it.  This also supplies power to the kitchen lights and outlets.  When I press the test on the breaker the lights go off and no power to the kitchen outlets. After reset the power is restored except to the exterior outlets.

Comment: The exterior outlets stopped working when I was building a bunny cage and using my air compressor and miter saw at the same time.

Comment: I'm going to 2nd Freeman 's post. Have you cycled all gfci outlets and verified they  have power? How many outside plugs are there? Are ALL breakers in the ON position?